# Facebook AccessToken is null on re-opening application after a "full" close

Tags: android, facebook, parse-platform, facebook-access-token

I have an app that uses Facebook in combination with Parse to login users. 
My problem is that when I fully close the application and then open it again, my AccessToken from Facebook is null. Seems like it is not stored from Session to session for some reason. 
When I just log out and then in again, it works fine.  Anyone experienced the same issue?
This is how I log in the users:

```
List<String> permissions = Arrays.asList("public_profile");
            ParseFacebookUtils.logInWithReadPermissionsInBackground(this, permissions, new LogInCallback() {
                @Override
                public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException err) {

                if (user == null) {
                    //Error...
                } else if (user.isNew()) {
                    //Some code...
                    mCurrentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();

                } else {
                    //Some code...
                    mCurrentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

add `Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);` in `onCreate()` of `your_app extends Application`

Comment: The weird thing is that when I open after a close the first time, I have an valid access token when running the application code, but it becomes null when the first activity starts.

Comment: how do access the access token

Comment: I check if its valid like this:

public boolean isLoggedIn(){
        AccessToken token = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
        return token != null;
    }